# What are some Mathematica packages used for general relativity?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, physics, packages, tensors

Could you suggest any Mathematica packages that are used for General relativity calculations? Id like to write code to solve the Schwarzchild Lagrangian equation.

Comment: I think you will get better answer on this from google. I typed **General relativity package mathematica** and google gave many hits. I know xAct is good package for tensor calculus.   You can also check [integrating-hamiltons-equations-for-the-schwarzschild-metric](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190608/integrating-hamiltons-equations-for-the-schwarzschild-metric) and [plotting-animating-a-test-planet-around-a-star](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285459/plotting-animating-a-test-planet-around-a-star)

Comment: btw, just saying **help me to write the code to solve Schwarzchild Lagrangian equation ?** is not really a good question for this forum. It might be good question to give to chatGPT though.

Comment: Dear Rishabh! Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange. Here we provide support to your faulty code instead of providing a full code in itself for a given problem. The thing you need to do is to first try to come up with your own code first, if you are stuck or getting any errors, you can definitely ask the community to help you out !

Comment: I am not really sure what you want to do: solve geodesics equations for the Schwarzschild metric numerically? That does not really require GR specific methods apart from computing Christoffel symbols which one could just plug in from literature: for the Schwarzschild metric there are on,y a few quite simple ones.

Answer (score 5):

I just would like to point out some approaches, of a quite broad spectrum, that are used wrt to General Relativity with Wolfram Language. This is a collection of works - some are packages, some use packages, some are research papers. Most of it I am aware about through a lot of editorial work at https://wolfr.am/PubMat and https://wolfr.am/StaffPicks

- MOST RECENT: **Computational General Relativity in the Wolfram Language using Gravitas I: Symbolic and Analytic Computation.** Quite big new development.

  - PAPER: https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.07508
  - AUTHOR: https://twitter.com/getjonwithit/status/1691606366966657280
- FUN: [Visualizing Interstellar's Wormhole (Christopher Nolan Movie) with Kip S. Thorne et al. Algorithm](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/852052)
- FUN: [How black holes and accretion disks around them actually look](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2017849)
- A PACKAGE: [Rotating black holes: corrections to the Kerr metric package](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2249688)
- RESEARCH using PACKAGES: [Algebraic classification of the gravitational field in Weyl-Cartan spacetimes](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2996064)
- How BIG NAMES do research: [Dynamical Gravastars, Stephen Adler, Institute for Advanced Study](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2820793)
- MODER EXPERIMENT: [Tilt-to-length coupling in LISA Pathfinder: Analytical modeling](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2987214)

#### FRESH RESEARCH:

- [Self-collision of a portal wormhole](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2286081)
- [Pseudospectra of Holographic Quasinormal Modes](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3002089)
- [Testing the Speed of Gravity with Black Hole Ringdown](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2948738)
- [Testing the Speed of Gravity with Black Hole Ringdown: Schwarzschild BH in GR](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2988459)

#### Examples of the [Wolfram Physics Project](https://www.wolframphysics.org/):

- [Black hole entanglement entropy from causal graphs](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2959318)
- [Quantum gravity in (2+1) dimensions and multiway system](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2312765)
- [Towards discretizing metric-affine gravity via elastic hypergraphs](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2311601)
- [Hunting for black holes](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2029731)
- [Branchial wormholes](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2578586)